# How to use an Observable object in a WinJS ListView

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs

I want to use an observable object within a ListView in the Windows 8 RT (Developer Preview from BUILD 2011) (using JavaScript).

The code below seems like it should work. It has a simple template for displaying a title and a description of each object in the HTML and a basic use of the WinJS.UI.Listview component.

I expect to see a list of objects, but always see the "wait spinner" when the list contains [observables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229801.aspx).

Experimentally, I've noticed that if the code doesn't convert the entire list (all but 3) to observables, then the list will show up. From doing some debugging, it would appear that it's somehow timing related and that the WinJS framework miscounts and fails to render the ListView entirely (as some of the objects are "pending") for some reason (the miscount confusion happens deep in a call to realizeItems in the ScrollView code).  If I comment out the `enableFirstChanceException` function call, it fails while comparing two objects (but I don't know if it's relevant) in the function itemChanged (*circular reference in value argument not supported*).

Any idea on how to make this work with observable objects?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=1024, height=768" />
    <title>WinWebApp1</title>
    <!-- WinJS references -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/winjs/css/ui-dark.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/WinJS/js/base.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/WinJS/js/ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/WinJS/js/binding.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/WinJS/js/controls.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/WinJS/js/res.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/WinJS/js/animations.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/WinJS/js/uicollections.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/WinJS/js/wwaapp.js"></script>
    <!-- WinWebApp1 references -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/default.css" />
    <script src="/js/default.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="itemTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template" >
        <div class="itemContainer">

            <!-- Displays the "title" field. -->
            <div class="itemTitle" data-win-bind="innerText: title">
            </div>

            <!-- Displays the "description" field.  -->
            <div class="itemDescription" data-win-bind="innerText: description">
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ViewBox">
        <div class="fixed-layout">
            <div id="basicListView" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" data-win-options="{itemRenderer: itemTemplate}">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    // Uncomment the following line to enable first chance exceptions.
    //Debug.enableFirstChanceException(true);

    var myData = [
    { title: "Banana", description: "Banana Frozen Yogurt"},
    { title: "Orange", description: "Orange Sherbet"},
    { title: "Vanilla", description: "Vanilla Ice Cream"},
    { title: "Mint", description: "Mint Gelato"},
    { title: "Strawberry", description: "Strawberry Sorbet"},
    { title: "Kiwi", description: "Kiwi Sorbet" }
    ];

    // this works:
    //var myDataSource = new WinJS.UI.ArrayDataSource(myData);

    // this does not:
    for (var i = 0; i < myData.length ; i++) {
        myData[i] = WinJS.Binding.as(myData[i]);
    }
    var myDataSource = new WinJS.UI.ArrayDataSource(myData);

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (e) {
        WinJS.UI.processAll()
            .then(function () {
                var basicListView = WinJS.UI.getControl(document.getElementById("basicListView"));
                basicListView.dataSource = myDataSource;

            // when the observable works correctly, this should work (and live change the list)
            //setTimeout(function () {
            //    basicListView.refresh();
            //    myData[0].title = "Yellow Banana";
            //    myData[5].title = "Kiwisicle";
            //}, 3000);
        });
    });
    WinJS.Application.start();
})();
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I may be running into this.

Comment: I ran into a separate issue I think, my observable objects update correctly. My problem was with the Semantic Zoom control not updating its layout correctly.